# Vee-validate Basic example not working - errors not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm trying to make a simple form validation page work with vee-validate. Something appears to be broken though, and I am unsure what exactly I am doing wrong.

How am I getting the error: `errors not defined`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>asdfasd</h1>
    <form action='#' method='POST'>
      <input v-validate="'required|email'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('email_primary') }" name="email_primary" type="text" placeholder="email_primary">
      <span v-show="errors.has('email_primary')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('email_primary') }}</span>
      <button class="button is-link" name='submitform' value='go'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/3.0.5/vee-validate.full.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    Vue.use(VeeValidate);
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      template: '#app',
      data() {
        return {
          email_primary: null
        };
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seems to use `veevalidate` 3 instead of veeValidate 2. I have updated the veevalidate to version 2 in my answer as well as adding `v-model="email_primary"`

Since you have a template already, I have removed `template: '#app',`. Kindly see below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <head>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>asdfasd</h1>
            <form action='#' method='POST'>
                <input v-model="email_primary" v-validate="'required|email'"
                    :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('email_primary') }"
                    name="email_primary" type="text" placeholder="email_primary">
                <span v-show="errors.has('email_primary')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('email_primary') }}</span>
                <button class="button is-link" name='submitform' value='go'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/2.2.15/vee-validate.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            Vue.use(VeeValidate);
            new Vue({
                el: "#app",                
                data() {
                    return {
                        email_primary: null
                    };
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kikuyu1/nw6p952f/1/). I hope my answer will help.